# GHC: segmentation fault under strange conditions

Tags: linux, haskell, segmentation-fault, ghc, ffi

Toady I updated my developing machine from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (or `ghc 6.12.1` to `ghc 7.4.1`) and I run into a very strange behavior at my currenct project.

After some hours, I reduced it to the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Data.Word
import Text.Printf
import Foreign

foreign import ccall "dynamic"
   code_void :: FunPtr (IO ()) -> (IO ())

main :: IO ()
main = do
  entryPtr <- (mallocBytes 2)
  poke entryPtr (0xc390 :: Word16) -- nop (0x90); ret(0xc3) (little endian order)

  _ <- printf "entry point: 0x%08x\n" ((fromIntegral $ ptrToIntPtr entryPtr) :: Int)
  _ <- getLine -- for debugging
  code_void $ castPtrToFunPtr entryPtr
  putStrLn "welcome back"
```

I'm trying to generate some code at run-time, jump to it, and come back again.
Using a Makefile, everything is fine:

```
$ make 
ghc --make -Wall -O2 Main.hs -o stackoverflow_segv
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking stackoverflow_segv ...
./stackoverflow_segv
entry point: 0x098d77e0

welcome back
```

However, if I call the binary directly from the shell:

```
$ ./stackoverflow_segv 
entry point: 0x092547e0

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This behavior is reproducible (luckily?).

Using `gdb`, `objdump` and `/proc` I figured out:

```
$ gdb -q stackoverflow_segv
Reading symbols from /home/lewurm/stackoverflow/stackoverflow_segv...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/lewurm/stackoverflow/stackoverflow_segv
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
entry point: 0x080fc810
```

before pressing enter, I switch to a second terminal:

```
$ cat /proc/`pgrep stackoverflow`/maps
[...]
08048000-080ea000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2492678    /home/lewurm/stackoverflow/stackoverflow_segv
080ea000-080eb000 r--p 000a2000 08:01 2492678    /home/lewurm/stackoverflow/stackoverflow_segv
080eb000-080f1000 rw-p 000a3000 08:01 2492678    /home/lewurm/stackoverflow/stackoverflow_segv
080f1000-08115000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
[...]
```

and back again:

```
<enter>
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804ce3c in s2aV_info ()
```

Boo. Let's see what this code does:

```
$ objdump -D stackoverflow_segv | grep -C 3 804ce3c
 804ce31:       89 44 24 4c             mov    %eax,0x4c(%esp)
 804ce35:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 804ce38:       8b 44 24 4c             mov    0x4c(%esp),%eax
 804ce3c:       ff d0                   call   *%eax
 804ce3e:       83 c4 0c                add    $0xc,%esp
 804ce41:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 804ce44:       8b 44 24 54             mov    0x54(%esp),%eax
```

uhm, jumping to `*%eax`. What was `%eax` again?

```
 (gdb) info reg eax
 eax            0x80fc810        135251984
```

Well, actually it's just the code buffer. Looking up `/proc/*/maps` tells us, that this page isn't executeable (`rw-p`, right?). *But*, it's the same situation when executing it within `make`.

What is wrong here?

btw, the code is also available via [gist](https://gist.github.com/2503293)

edit: [ghc bug report](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/6059)

Comment: Works fine from the command line here (openSUSE 11.4, x86_64). Could be Ubuntu's fault? Try with a self-built GHC if you have the time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it with the binary package from [haskell.org](http://www.haskell.org/ghc): (1) ghc-7.4.1, still the same problem. (2) ghc-7.2.2 not any more \o/ nice! (3) ghc-6.12.1 likewise. Do you think I should report that as a bug at the GHC folks?

Comment: The vanilla binary (unknown-linux)? I get the same behaviour as you if I use 7.2.2 instead of 7.4.1, though. Strange indeed.

Comment: Oh, now it also segfaults with the Makefile if I use 7.2.2. Stranger and strangerer.

Comment: yes, vanillia binary. currently I'm diffing `ghc -v` output between 7.4.1 and 7.2.2. the latter one has an additional `-lHSffi` flag at the linker stage, but 7.4.1 not.

Comment: segfault in the Makefile, but not on the shell?

Comment: I get no segfaults with 7.4.1, but all versions before that (6.12.3, 7.0.2, 7.2.1, 7.2.2) that I tried segfault both from the shell and via make.

Comment: No segfaults whatsoever on 32-bits (openSUSE 12.1).

Comment: I have been using GHC 7.4.1 on a mac for a while, and get bizarre segfaults pretty regularly.  They seem to be random though, as often the exact same action doesn't segfault when run a second time.  Not being able to reproduce the problem, I don't have a bug to file beyond "seems strangely unstable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary solution is to use `mprotect(3)` and set the memory region explicitly as executable. `mprotect(3)` requires a aligned memory block, therefore `memalign(3)` is required.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where

import Data.Word
import Text.Printf
import Foreign
import Foreign.C.Types

foreign import ccall "dynamic"
   code_void :: FunPtr (IO ()) -> (IO ())

foreign import ccall "static sys/mman.h"
  mprotect :: CUInt -> CUInt -> Int -> IO ()

foreign import ccall "static stdlib.h"
  memalign :: CUInt -> CUInt -> IO (Ptr a)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  entryPtr <- memalign 0x1000 0x2
  poke entryPtr (0xc390 :: Word16) -- nop (0x90); ret(0xc3) (little endian order)
  let i_entry = (fromIntegral $ ptrToIntPtr entryPtr) :: Int
  -- 0x7 = PROT_{READ,WRITE,EXEC}
  mprotect (fromIntegral i_entry) 2 0x7

  _ <- printf "entry point: 0x%08x\n" i_entry
  _ <- getLine -- for debugging
  code_void $ castPtrToFunPtr entryPtr
  putStrLn "welcome back"
```